# Positions for visualisations

Tags: training

where I can download positions for visualisation training? I am not looking for diagrams, I would like to have only position record saved in standard chess notation.

Or are there such a book?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what exactly constitutes "visualisation training", as opposed to just training tactics, i.e. solving puzzles.

Comment: Yes, but withoud diagrams, for example "visualise and solve exercise where white position is: Kg1, Qe7,g6 and  black is Kg8.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The problem is probably, that positions are usually given in FEN. And normal tactic puzzles are so crowded, it will take a while to get everything into your head.

Comment: Just making sure here, cause this sounds a lot more like Blind Folded Chess... Is that what you're talking about here?

Comment: 1. Qf7+ Kh8 2. Qh8#

Answer (score 1):

Visualization training is visualizing moves on the board **WITHOUT looking at the board**, like:

- Tell all the squares controlled by a knight on d4
- All the shortest paths to move a knight from a3 to h8
- How a Qa5 can attack a Rh4 without being captured
- How a Nc4 can check a Kb7 defended by Bb6 without being captured

etc., etc.

you might laugh and think it is easy, but it is not. Try a series of them randomly created and write down your answers then compare them to what you see while looking at the board.

Fun stuff.

Purpose?
It makes you a better calculator when looking at positions during your game. You will eventually instantly see multi-move paths that pieces can take across the board, especially knights.

Answer (score 0):

Practice technique.

One of the things that you can do is to have your opponents king in the center of the board, your king doesn't have to even be on the board. The going thru each possible position with a single major or minor piece for your opponent and the same for you, with your single major or minor piece attempt to fork, double attack or skewer the opponents king to his other piece in one move. Obviously it will not be possible with every position or actually fewer than more often. It will then help you automatically visualize where are good squares to move your minor and major piece and create a visual habit for immediate tactical positions for you pieces.

Answer (score 0):

[This ICC video](http://www.chessclub.com/videos/improve-your-chess-the-3-types-of-chess-vision) contains visualization exercises. It also covers tactical vision and board vision.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4dxI.jpg) helps. It's a type of chess puzzle designed by GM Maurice Ashley. Here's a Reddit discussion of he same - [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/4po8xm/how_good_is_your_chess_visualization/)